# Need to execute function twice to get result

Tags: javascript

I have two functions, first function is "createTables" for generating tables into different divs and second function is "compare" for comparing these tables.
These two functions are part of one function "doIT" but I need to execute function "doIT" twice.. first times it's saying "Cannot read property 'isEqualNode' of undefined". Any way to fix it?

```
function compare()
{
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("rtables");
  if (elems[0].isEqualNode(elems[1])) {
    alert("Elements are equal");
  } else {
  alert("Elements are NOT equal");
  }
}
```

Comment: Apparently there are no elements with the class `rtables` when `compare` is called.

Comment: Are you calling your function before your HTML has been rendered?

Comment: Both functions are called at the same time.

Comment: Is there any asynchronous code involved? (E.g., an Ajax call to get content for the tables?) Please [edit] your question to show details of the other functions (or at least, a minimal version of them). As it stands there isn't really enough information to answer it without guessing.

Comment: Can't give a good answer without seeing all the code, but I suspect you could end up with something that looks like `compare(createTables());` where `createTables()` returns the elements it's (I'm assuming) inserting into the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

When you compare function runs on the first try, the DOM tree isn't updated yet with your new tables; thus there are no elements with `rtables`.

The second time you call it, the first part doesn't need to be done since the DOM has been updated, which is why your `compare` method works on the second try.

This is because the browser has to wait for javascript to finish, to render any DOM updates (most browsers update the DOM in a single threaded implementation).

The simplest way to do this is to split your function into two, and call the second one (`compare`) with a timeout to give the browser a chance to update the DOM.

The other way is to wrap your compare call in a `setTimeout` which should give the browser a chance to update the DOM cache.

This should solve your problem and is also good programming practice - a function should only do one specific thing, which makes it easier to debug things. If you have one function doing three different things, then it makes it harder to track down bugs and soon you have a multiline monster.

Comment: I though its because of that but problem is I need to call it when button is clicked so thats why both are in same function.. When I tried input wait between these functions its delaying main function  which is called when button is clicked.. 

Comment: The other way (not so simple) is implement a `setTimeout` on your `compare` with the caller.

Comment: Ok I will try it later Im actually in bed.. 5 am.. IT life  Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: There should be function ifDOMRendered .. how can I guess the time for setTimeout when its different everytime and I need to compare asap